# How do I change the orientation of a table in a BIRT report

Tags: birt

I need to change the orientation of a table in a BIRT report so that the table header is vertical instead of horizontal.

Is this possible? I don't want to use a Crosstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in box (up to 3.7). You have to use 3'd party libs like [that one](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/birt-controls-lib/).

Comment: the 3rd party library you linked doesn't provide functionality to change the orientation.

Answer (score 4):

It seems this thread is still being pointed at so I posted an example of a horizontal table layout using a crosstab. I know it won't help the original author but others following this thread now may find this helpful.

To create the horizontal grouping, first create your query like normal, then create a Data Cube. In this data cube, drag each field that you want into a group.  Then drag a new crosstab on the report and drag each field into the top right column group area. It will create a new header row for each field. Don't put anything in the left side (Rows) and don't put anything in the measure field (bottom-right). This will create labels on the left... and the data will extend out to the right.

The report design example can be downloaded from: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/1079-horizontal-table-using-crosstab/

Virgil

Answer (score 2):

If you want dataset records to be reported *across* the page, this would have to be done via a crosstab.

If you want dataset records to be reported *down* the page, this can't be done automatically as far as I know. However, it can be done by inserting a new detail line in your report table object for each database field to be reported, then moving column headings from the heading row into the first column's detail rows and moving record values into the second column's detail rows.

So, for example, a report with 6 columns in it would become a two column report with six detail rows.