# show row values horizontally in BIRT report

Tags: birt

My scenario is that 
default table shown in BIRT is like that

col1   |   col2

val1      |               val1

val2        |             val2

val3        |             val3

but I want show table like as below

column 1  | val1  val2  val3

column 2  | val1  val2  val3   in table

Please give me a suggestions how can I do it,it really helpful for me

thanks in Advance.

[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPLOW.png)

Comment: Possible duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754802/how-do-i-change-the-orientation-of-a-table-in-a-birt-report

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 headers and map the values in the column as `val1 val2 val3`. For example, see the image below:

[image]

Comment: further doubts elaborate ?

Comment: Thank you for reply,but I do not get correct output,header display multiple times,please see the image for reference